# I am getting an RPC error when trying to run any Bitcoin-cli commands on Ubuntu

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

I asked this question on AskUbuntu and was told to post it here.

https://askubuntu.com/q/1373657/1519292

I am trying to follow the Mastering Bitcoin tutorial. After compiling Bitcoin Core, and changing the datadir to my external hard drive in the config file, I get the following error any time I try a Bitcoin-cli command:

error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and RPC password is not set. See -rpcpassword and -stdinrpcpass. Configuration file: (/media/XXXX/f1ebcea0-6304-4580-9ce2-1416dc0be49f/BlockchainData/bitcoin.conf)

When I search the forums, the only solution to this error is that Bitcoind was not running, but I confirmed that it is running. I suspect it has something to do with my hard drive permissions or admin level, but everything seems to be set up properly.

Comment: Share your complete bitcoin.conf file contents assuming you are trying this on testnet, else share relevant things from config file

Comment: datadir=/media/XXXX/f1ebcea0-6304-4580-9ce2-1416dc0be49f/BlockchainData is the only thing i have in it

Comment: Save this in bitcoin.conf apart from datadir: `rpcport=8332 rpcuser=SOMEUSERNAME rpcpassword=SOMEPASS` and use `bitcoin-cli datadir=/media/XXXX/f1ebcea0-6304-4580-9ce2-1416dc0be49f/BlockchainData -getinfo`

Comment: This did not solve the issue. I resorted to re-formatting my drive and got a larger home drive. Thank you for the help though.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are probably starting the daemon with a non-standard data directory, you'll need to specify the datadir every time you use the bitcoin-cli command, like this:

```
bitcoin-cli -datadir=/mnt/bitcoin YOUR_COMMMAND
```

Source: https://howchoo.com/bitcoin/run-bitcoin-full-node-raspberry-pi

Comment: I already re-formatted my hard drive, thank you for the help though